# How to display the contents of a single row in a table using mysql command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line, row

I'm trying to find the value stored in 'home' row in the table 'wp_options' in the database 'wordpress'.

What is the sequence of commands to type in mysql command line to get that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
mysql -B -N -e "SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='home'" wordpress
```

The `-B` option removes the "box" of dashes around the result.

The `-N` option removes the column header from the result.

The `-e "query"` option allows you to run a SQL query.

The last argument is the name of the database.